# Add structured files in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

In my daily routines I frequently need to add a couple of folder and files. For example when I am creating a maven module, I have to add a `pom` file, `src/main/java` folders with a source file. This process is really cumbersome. Is there any easy way to adding parameterised folders and files in project as `file templates`?

Comment: I believe you can copy-paste an empty file structure on the file system, and intellij will recognize that the structure has been added, and prompt if you wish to add them to version control.

Comment: This is currently how I am doing. But this requires a lot of tasks such as manually renaming folder and files tasks. This is not only cumbersome but also error prone. It is quite possible to missing somewhere to forget renaming. I would like to create a template and trigger it with necessary parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available for complete modules: you can do Tools | Save Project as Template... to save a directory structure as a template, and then select that template in the File | New Module... dialog.

For pieces of code which are smaller than a module, unfortunately no equivalent feature is available. You can write your own plugin to create the necessary structure for you.

Comment: Thanks @yole. Is it worth filing an issue in IDEA tracker? This would be good asset to JetBrains product.